# Search element in sorted matrix

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix

I have a mission to search an element in a sorted matrix in the most effective way(I think O(logN)).

My code currently is O(N<sup>2</sup>) and I'm trying to figure out how to do it more effectively.

It's a sorted matrix, and also going by square:

[image]

```
{1, 2, 5, 6
 4, 3, 8, 7
 13,14,9,10
 16,15,12,11 }  ---->  {1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}
```

This sorted way is like a clock.

This is my code:

```
public static boolean search(int[][] mat, int num) {
    int rows = mat.length / 2;
    int columns = mat[0].length / 2;
    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (mat[i][j] == num) {
                System.out.println("row= " + i + "\n" + "col= " + j);
            } else if(mat[i][j] < num){
                i++;
            } else if(mat[i][j] > num){
                j--;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Q: Could you show us how you've defined, and how you initialize "mat"?  Q: What  exactly do you mean by "sorted", "going by square" or "like a clock"?  Please clarify.  Q: Does the snippet you posted compile (without errors)?

Comment: Your are searching only in the top left quarter of the matrix

Comment: i have entered an example with image.